# When using Python 2.7's multiprocessing.Pool, how do I tell which worker got which argument?

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, python-multiprocessing

I just started using Python 2.7's `multiprocessing` module in a script, like this:

```
import multiprocessing

def crunch(a):
    results = []

    # do something

    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
    args = ['foo', 'bar', 'bla']
    results_list = pool.map(crunch, args)
```

For some reason, one of the worker processes is taking a very long time, while all other workers seem to have finished according to the CPU activity in Linux's `top` utility. How do I tell which argument among 'foo', 'bar', and 'bla' was passed to the slow worker (so that I can hopefully figure out why it's so slow)?

Comment: Just a random thought, won't the easiest way to find out which one is slow just having each worker write the argument they started working on to a file and do the same when the task was completed? Then you just have to check which argument has started but didn't write a complete message